# Why is this sequential array loop slower than a loop that uses a "lookup" array?

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I've been studying cache locality recently and I'm trying to understand how CPUs access memory.  I wrote an experiment to see if there was a performance difference when looping an array sequentially vs. using a lookup table of some sort to index into the data array.  I was surprised to find the lookup method slightly faster.  My code is below.  I compiled with GCC on Windows (MinGW).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    DWORD dwElapsed, dwStartTime;

    //random arrangement of keys to lookup
    int lookup_arr[] = {0, 3, 8, 7, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9};

    //data for both loops
    int data_arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int data_arr2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    //first loop, sequential access
    dwStartTime = GetTickCount();
    for (int n = 0; n < 9000000; n++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            data_arr1[i]++;
    }
    dwElapsed = GetTickCount() - dwStartTime;
    printf("Normal loop completed: %d\n", dwElapsed);

    //second loop, indexes into data_arr2 using the lookup array
    dwStartTime = GetTickCount();
    for (int n = 0; n < 9000000; n++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            data_arr2[lookup_arr[i]]++;
    }
    dwElapsed = GetTickCount() - dwStartTime;
    printf("Lookup loop completed: %d\n", dwElapsed);

    return 0;
}
```

Running this, I get:

```
Normal loop completed: 375
Lookup loop completed: 297
```

Comment: How many times did you run this program?

Comment: Did you check the assembler output? And what optimizations flag did you use?

Comment: You're compiling with optimizations enabled, right?

Comment: You need to span a much larger range of memory (512k or greater) if you want to see cache coherence effects - and you will want to turn off optimization to see the "raw, underlying" performance. I would recommend you have a really big random array for the lookup and try again.

Comment: What happens if you have your "look up" array loop running first? What if you run each "many times" and average their performance? Many other things may be happening at the same time that affect timing of a short loop. A measurement is meaningless without an estimate of the error...

Comment: Pretty sure that on your second loop when i == 9 you will be accessing a invalid position...

Comment: @HAL 10 times. I have not used optimization.  I just tried -O1 and execution time goes below the millisecond resolution.  Perhaps I should find a way to create a bigger sample size.

Comment: I have flipped the loops and that does change the timing, but the lookup loop is still faster (344) compared to the sequential loop which is still 375.

Comment: Can you try to invert loops? Put the second in first position.

Comment: The reason that optimization makes the time fall to "zero" is that when you don't do anything with the results, the optimizer says "I don't need this calculation since you don't use the result". Which is why, in my code below, I add the elements together and print the sum. when I leave out the printf() statement, time plummets (even though it happens outside the timing loop), demonstrating that the optimizer is "clever" like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on my earlier comments, here is how you do this kind of thing.

1. Repeated measurements
2. Estimate error
3. Large memory block
4. Randomized vs linear indices (so either way you have an indirection)

The result is a significant difference in speed with the "randomized indexing".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 1000000

int main(void) {
  int *rArr;
  int *rInd; // randomized indices
  int *lInd; // linear indices
  int ii;

  rArr = malloc(N * sizeof(int) );
  rInd = malloc(N * sizeof(int) );
  lInd = malloc(N * sizeof(int) );

  for(ii = 0; ii < N; ii++) {
    lInd[ii] = ii;
    rArr[ii] = rand();
    rInd[ii] = rand()%N;
  }

  int loopCount;
  int sum;
  time_t startT, stopT;
  double dt, totalT=0, tt2=0;

  startT = clock();
  for(loopCount = 0; loopCount < 100; loopCount++) {
    for(ii = 0; ii < N; ii++) {
      sum += rArr[lInd[ii]];
    }
    stopT = clock();
    dt = stopT - startT;
    totalT += dt;
    tt2 += dt * dt;
    startT = stopT;
  }
  printf("sum is %d\n", sum);
  printf("total time: %lf += %lf\n", totalT/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC), (tt2 - totalT * totalT / 100.0)/100.0 / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));

  totalT = 0; tt2 = 0;
  startT = clock();
  for(loopCount = 0; loopCount < 100; loopCount++) {
    for(ii = 0; ii < N; ii++) {
      sum += rArr[rInd[ii]];
    }
    stopT = clock();
    dt = stopT - startT;
    totalT += dt;
    tt2 += dt * dt;
    startT = stopT;
  }
  printf("sum is %d\n", sum);
  printf("total time: %lf += %lf\n", totalT/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC), sqrt((tt2 - totalT * totalT / 100.0)/100.0) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
}
```

Result - the sequential access is > 2x faster (on my machine):

```
sum is -1444272372
total time: 0.396539 += 0.000219
sum is 546230204
total time: 0.756407 += 0.001165
```

With `-O3` optimization, the difference is even starker - a full 3x faster:

```
sum is -318372465
total time: 0.142444 += 0.013230
sum is 1672130111
total time: 0.455804 += 0.000402
```

Comment: In case anyone intends to use this method in future for doing performance measurements, note that the "error" I compute is the standard deviation on a SINGLE measurement - so strictly speaking the number I should have reported is "time per loop" which is 100 times smaller (and then the error is right). `3.96 +- 0.22 ms per loop vs 7.56 +- 1.2 ms` would be more correct than what my (somewhat hastily written) code spits out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are compiling without optimizations turned on. With `-O2` g++ optimizes away everything so the run time is 0, and without the flag I get similar results.

After modifying the program so that values in `data_arr1` and `data_arr2` are actually used for something I get 78ms for both.