# Timing a block of code with C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, time, timing

I am trying to compare the accuracy of timing methods with C++ and Java.

With C++ I usually use `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, I run the block of code I want to time for a certain amount of time and then calculate how long it took, based on how many times the block was executed.

With Java I usually use `System.nanoTime()`.

Which one is more accurate, the one I use for C++ or the one I use for Java? Is there any other way to time in C++ so I don't have to repeat the piece of code to get a proper measurement? Basically, is there a `System.nanoTime()` method for C++?

I am aware that both use system calls which cause considerable latencies. How does this distort the real value of the timing? Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every method has errors. Before you spend a great deal of time on this question, you have to ask yourself "how accurate do I need my answer to be"? Usually the solution is to run a loop / piece of code a number of times, and keep track of the mean / standard deviation of the measurement. This is a good way to get a handle on the repeatability of your measurement. After that, assume that latency is "comparable" between the "start time" and "stop time" calls (regardless of what function you used), and you have a framework to understand the issues.

Bottom line: `clock()` function typically gives microsecond accuracy.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20497193/1967396 for an example of how to go about this in C (in that instance, using a usec precision clock). There's the ability to use ns timing - see for example the answer to [clock_gettime() still not monotonic - alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483534/clock-gettime-still-not-monotonic-alternatives) which uses `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &tSpec);`

Note that you have to extract seconds and nanoseconds separately from that structure.

Comment: Can you really base the accuracy of the method by keeping track of the standard deviation when looping in a process? Your process is likely not the only process running on the system and the scheduler should be free to give it time whenever it feels to.

Comment: I said the standard deviation will give you a handle on **repeatability** : if you do it multiple times, do you get the same answer (almost the same thing as "precision"). This is different than **accuracy** : is it the right answer. You cannot know that without calibration. Sorry to be picky about nomenclature.

Comment: @bruce14 - other point to note - most of the clocks that are provided (other than "wall clock" clocks) measure time elapsed _in the process_ so they compensate for time your process was suspended. The `getrusage()` is particularly powerful in this regard.

Comment: I'm with you, but OP asked for accuracy, so that's why i questioned it. But you're totally right in your second comment and so my question isn't relevant anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using System.nanoTime() as it is still limited by the resolution that the machine you are running on can give you.

Also there are complications timing Java as the first few times through a function will be a lot slower until they get optimized for your system.

Virtually all modern systems use pre-emptive multi threading and multiple cores, etc - so all timings will vary from run to run. (For example if control gets switched away from your thread while it in the method).

To get reliable timings you need to

1. Warm up the system by running around the thing you are timing a few hundred times before starting.
2. Run the code for a good number of times and average the results.

The reliability issues are the same for any language so apply just as well to C as to Java so C may not need the warm-up loop but you will still need to take a lot of samples and average them.

Comment: A nice way to show the "warm up" effect (particularly noticeable when you involve network connections, but even memory cache can play) is to record the (total) elapsed time after each loop, then plot these values vs loop count. The slope of this curve may increase for the first few iterations, then stabilize. That's exactly the effect you are describing, I believe.

Comment: Caching etc may give some "warm up" effect even in C. In Java the effect is much more noticeable due to Just In Time Compilation. The first few times around it runs bytecode, then gradually more and more of the code gets turned into assembler tuned for the environment it is running on.

Comment: According to the standard, the times from `clock()` should be the CPU time used by your application, so getting switched out and then back in shouldn't affect it.  (Windows implementation of `clock()` is broken in this respect.)  Of course, being interrupted by another process, and then continuing, can have an impact on how much of your process memory is in cache, which in turn affects performance.

Comment: But being switched to another Thread in your application would not be detected...and you are relying on that behavior being consistent and reliable...